# ie div positioned absolute width bug

Tags: css, html, input, width

I have a DIV with position absolute that contains an INPUT field, i need this input to be centered vertically and horizontally inside the div which i have accomplished with display:block and text align, the problem is that the width property is not working the same way for IE (10 and below), the parent div have the proper width in chrome and firefox but a totally different one in IE10,9 and 8.

Just in case this information is relevant, the parent div is inside another div with position relative. I know it sounds like a question from back to the future but i was really surprised to notice that that im still having this issue after normalizer, etc.

Here's the code
[HTML and CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/KuEPu/)

```
<div>
    <input type="text" />
</div>

div {
    position:absolute;
    background: blue;
    width: 180px;
    padding:8px 0;
    display:block;
}

input {
    border-radius: 5px;
margin: 0;
height: 20px;
position: relative;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;   
}
```

Comment: @Andrei IE10 but im having the same issue with previous versions too

Comment: works fine for me in IE10

Comment: Works fine for me too in IE10

Comment: @Andrei Im now wondering if this caused by the outer divs, here's a test online and it's not working for me (notice the different width on the blue box on the right side of the navbar)
http://wearehellyeah.com/test/home_formacio.html

Comment: it can be browser's default css. Why don't you set width for the input?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the `em` units.

If you compare IE and Chrome you will see that the green bar in the menu is more to the left in IE than Chrome. That is because there is a pixel difference here and there in the font-size.

They are calculated differently. I think IE approximates differently.

Maybe instead of trying to make the 2 browsers look the same, you could make it look good on both browsers. Users will not know.

Use either a CSS file that gets added in IE browsers, or detect the browser with javascript and add classes on body (similar to modernizr), or use CSS hacks.

Comment: What would you recommend to do Andrei ? my body main font is in px and the rest of the fonts are relative to that font (16px). That does mean we just have to stop using ems if we need ie crossbrowsing ? Input width didnt help by the way.

Comment: I don't recommend that. `em` units should be fine. Maybe the padding calculated as em units too are the real problem.

Comment: I have change all the ems in the navbar for pxs and even when now the difference is way less obvious there's still a difference on how it looks in ie and firefox now. This is really annoying.

Comment: See my edit. I would advice you to focus on making them look good, than making them look the same.